# Stream audio from raspberry pi to bluetooth speaker

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I am trying to stream audio from  RPi 3 to bluetooth speaker.  I used bluetoothctl to pair and connect the bluetooth speaker to the RPI and I am able to connect to the speaker successfully.
I also integrated pulseaudio for redirecting the audio. pulseaudio is running as a root user.
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disable-shm --exit-idle-time=-1
Then I tried to play a stream in the background. I can see the video is playing  in TV but I can't hear any sound in TV as well as in speaker.

Any suggestions or guidance?

Comment: First, don't run pulseaudio as root, it's meant to be run as normal user. Second, use `pavucontrol` (requires X), `pacmd`, `pactl` etc. to find out what is going on, and if the media player application (you didn't say which one) is connected to the correct bluetooth sink, if the bluetooth sink is present at all, etc.